# Getting key of unique values in a nested dict within lists

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, iteration

I have a dict, which contains of elements with the following structure

```
{'task0': {'id': 0, 'successor':[<other elements>]}
```

Every element contains a unique id and a successor list of the mentioned elements. The can be also empty, which means, this element has no successors.

**Example**

```
a = {'task0': {'node_id': 0, 'successor': [{'task1': {'node_id': 1, 'successor': [{'task2': {'node_id': 2, 'successor': [{'task4': {'node_id': 4, 'successor': []}}, {'task5': {'node_id': 5, 'successor': []}}]}},  {'task3': {'node_id': 3, 'successor': []}}]}}]}}
```

**What I want**

```
def get_node_name_by_id(obj, id_search)
```

Example: def get_node_name_by_id(a, 3) ==  'task3'

```
def get_parent_id_by_child_id(obj, id_search)
```

Example: def get_parent_id_by_child_id(a, 3) == 1

**What I have so far**

```
def get_node_name_by_id(obj, id_search):
    for k,v in obj.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v,dict):
            if v['node_id'] is id_search:
                return k
            elif v['successor']:
                    for e in v['successor']:
                        return get_node_name_by_id(e, id_search)
```

-> Problem: If the id, which I am searching for, is not on place 1 of the list, I get `None` as a result.

-> For the second function, I have no clue how to implement it

**Question**

- How can I fix my problems, respectively, is there a smarter way to implement the first function?
- What would be a good implementation for the second function?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why task1 and task2 has '[' , is it a list inside a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, a list which contains dicts (which can be also contains dicts with lists a.s.o)

Comment: `if v['id'] is id` ? `is` instead of `in` ? I wouldn't recommend `id` since it is a reserved keyword. Also provide a verifiable example with real data in your dict, please.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: `id()` is a built-in function, not a keyword. Masking it could be a problem if you wanted to use the built-in only.

Comment: you're right. Not a good practice anyway (well, who uses `id` ?)

Comment: I'm sorry but pycripter tells me that the `a` expression has a problem and it's so complex I cannot figure it right.

Comment: Looks like I put a bracket wrong - my fault. I fixed it.

Comment: I think a tree will allow you to easily store this data in `O(n)` space and can be optimized by memoization on construction to retrieve data in `O(1)`. It will also be easier to visualize and debug.

Comment: Actually, the tree will be built by linking node objects. The dict will be updated/created at the same time, when nodes will be added to the tree. I will not use the dict for tree operations, e.g. cutting of a subtree etc.

Comment: Then why don't you build a tree and use the same operations on the tree itself? It'll be much easier to do so.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to make `successors` a list of `node_id`s instead of actual node-dictionaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on tobias_k comment, I found an easier way to store the information.
Because every node object has a unique ID, it is enough to store these IDs only.
The index of each sublist is the index of the node, for which the successors are defined.

```
successor_list = [[successors_node0], [successors_node1], [successors_node2], ..., [successors_nodeN]]
```

With the help of the ID, I can access to the node object (all node objects are stored in a list) to access on the object attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious issue that we did not see earlier was unconditional `return` statement in your inner loop.

You have to return something only if it is not `None`, else other items of the list other than the first one are ignored.

(note I have changed `iteritems` to `items` because it is python 3 compatible and also works with latest python 2.7 versions)

```
a = {'task0': {'node_id': 0, 'successor': [{'task1': {'node_id': 1, 'successor': [{'task2': {'node_id': 2, 'successor': [{'task4': {'node_id': 4, 'successor': []}}, {'task5': {'node_id': 5, 'successor': []}}]}},  {'task3': {'node_id': 3, 'successor': []}}]}}]}}

def get_node_name_by_id(obj, id_search):
    for k,v in obj.items():
        if isinstance(v,dict):
            if v['node_id'] is id_search:
                return k
            elif v['successor']:
                    for e in v['successor']:
                        r = get_node_name_by_id(e, id_search)
                        if r:
                            return r


print(get_node_name_by_id(a, 3))
```

output:

```
task3
```